Intermittent "Error establishing a database connection" errors with Wordpress on Docker, when using an external network
I'm trying to set up a simple installation of Wordpress using Docker. The Docker Compose file from the official image page works fine, but when I modify it as follows to connect to an external network (which I want to do in order to use an existing caddy-docker-proxy container as a reverse proxy), I get intermittent "Error establishing a database connection" errors:
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ********
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    networks:
      caddy:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.0.30

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ********
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      caddy:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.0.31
volumes:
  wordpress:
  db:

networks:
  caddy:
    external: true

The maddening thing is that while these errors seem to appear on many or most page loads, it often does work fine, and I can get all the way through a basic installation by just tediously refreshing the page every time I see the error. The system is a cheap cloud VM, very lightly loaded. I've looked at the Wordpress and and database logs, but have not found anything. What could the problem be? How can I troubleshoot this further?
Edit: The question was closed, so I can't add an answer, but I figured out the problem: I'm attaching two separate service stacks (Wordpress and Nextcloud), using two separate docker-compose.yml files, under two separate directories, to the same external network (in order to have caddy-docker-proxy route incoming web traffic to the appropriate service), and both service stacks define a db database service. While (by default) docker-compose uses the docker-compose.yml parent directory name as a prefix for the container names, which results in unique container names, it uses each service name exactly as specified as a service alias, and these aliases need not be unique. As the documentation puts it:

A network-wide alias can be shared by multiple containers, and even by
multiple services. If it is, then exactly which container the name
resolves to is not guaranteed.

So in my case, since the Nextcloud and Wordpress applications were both pointed at db services, they were randomly trying to access each other's databases and failing.
One solution is to add unique aliases and use them instead of the service names. E.g., in my original docker-compose.yml file given above, replace the db service's networks section with the following:
networks:
  caddy:
    ipv4_address: 172.16.0.30
    aliases:
      - wordpress_db

and replace the wordpress service's WORDPRESS_DB_NAME line with the following:
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: wordpress_db

It turns out that this issue is the subject of a three year old discussion at the Docker Github repo and forums:

https://forums.docker.com/t/add-option-to-remove-service-name-as-default-alias-on-networks/106172
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8223


Use depends_on in your Docker file so that WordPress starts only after the database is ready. In this code snippet:
wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ********
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    networks:
      caddy:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.0.30

By doing this, it should improve the communication between the database and your application, as WordPress will depend on the database's availability to start.
I'm not sure about your internal DB configuration, but check if the my.cnf in this Docker is set for more connections according to your application's demand, under max_connections.

Simple depends_on: may not be enough here; it will wait for the database to exist but it may not be running yet.  Also see Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y.
